# Is there performance difference between "SET ROWCOUNT" and "TOP"?

Tags: performance, sybase-ase

I need to select batches of N rows from a large table.

I know of two ways of doing this:

1. `SET ROWCOUNT`

   ```
   SET ROWCOUNT ####
   SELECT something FROM table WHERE clauses
   SET ROWCOUNT 0 -- rowcount is only needed for the one query above.
   ```
2. `TOP`

   ```
    SELECT TOP ### something FROM table WHERE clauses
   ```

## Is there any performance difference (or any other reason to pick one over another) between the two solutions?

***Notes:***

- If it matters, Sybase ASE is version 15.
- The query is a single `SELECT` statement. The limit will not apply to any other statements (so [usual reasons](https://sqlstudies.com/2013/10/07/use-top-instead-of-set-rowcount/) to pick *rowcount* over *top* don't apply).
- The order of the rows does not matter

***Research done:***

- This [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/468764/119280) has accepted answer which claims no difference without any supporting references; and another answer that shows a possible un-measured difference for MS SQL server (which I'm not sure applies to Sybase as the reference is from Microsoft).

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking ... performance should be the same.

Technically speaking ... it depends on the query; for example, if the `TOP` is used within the confines of a derived table then you may see different performance depending on how/if the optimizer flattens the query.

To answer the question for a given query(s), run some tests with the following options enabled:

```
set showplan on
set statistics io,time on
go
-- set rowcount XXX
select [top] ...
-- set rowcount 0
go
```

You'll want to run the query a couple times to make sure data has been pulled from disk so that you can compare in-memory data queries to each other.

Obviously you'll then want to compare the 2x query plans as well as the IOs and timings (keeping in mind that **times** can vary greatly based on duration of blocking and/or time spent on the wait queue waiting to run on a dataserver engine). IOs should be comparable on repeat runs, but for timings you'll likely want to run each query a few times and take the average.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET ROWCOUNT ####
SELECT something FROM table WHERE clauses
SET ROWCOUNT 0 --
```

In this query ,optimizer  do not include "`SET ROWCOUNT ####`" part in query plan therefore no cost.

It is rarely use and there is not much reason to use because we are not able to specify any criteria.

```
SELECT TOP ### something FROM table WHERE clauses
```

Generally  `TOP` is accompanied by `order clause`  though not necessary.

`TOP` is evaluated query plan hence it has cost.

so SET rowcount will perform little better.

Main Difference

TOP work only on the query it is use.

`SET ROWCOUNT` work for current SCOPE.There for all query are affected by `SET ROWCOUNT` in that scope including trigger.

Suppose ,

```
SET RowCount 2
```

and actually (by logic) 4 rows should be affected in trigger .but only 2 rows will be affected because of SET RowCount 2

So it is not safe to use SET ROWCOUNT.

I heard `SET ROWCOUNT` will be depreciated in next version.

Comment: `TOP is evaluated query plan hence it has cost.` - do you have citation that it's true for Sybase ASE?

Comment: Also, your second half of the answer is 100% irrelevant, sorry. I specifically indicated that the rowcount is set and unset over a single select query only